# Json decode comes up as NULL

Tags: php, json

```
#input url
$url = 'http://www.example.com';

#get the data
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$contents = utf8_encode($json); 

#convert to php array
$php_array = json_decode($json);
var_dump($php_array); 
exit;
```

I'm trying to decode a website but once I decode it my page comes up as NULL, does anyone know how I can fix it? Thanks

Comment: Could you add a sample content of `$json`?

Comment: getting this `array(3) { ["timestamp"]=> string(8) "10:19:12" ["error_num"]=> int(404) ["error_msg"]=> string(20) "File Not Found Error" }` by using CURL

Comment: what is the exact code for that?

Comment: example given below

Answer (score 2):

In your case http://www.example.com this URL returns 404 error. so `file_get_contents($url)` get `null` value.

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$json = file_get_contents($url); // HTTP 404
echo $json; //returns null
```

This works fine

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.example.com';
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

$php_array = json_decode($output, true); // true for returning to an array

echo "<pre>";
print_r($php_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Extra Tip:
I too faced `null` issue sometimes. You could ask `json_last_error()` to get definite information.

Comment: @Tim check out this answer

Comment: It didm't help.

Comment: the link you provided throws HTTP 404 error. so it returns null value and you cannot json_decode the null value @Tim

Comment: Is there no way around that?

Comment: Yes there is you can do cURL call

Comment: Have you installed `curl` on your machine?

Comment: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` run this and search for keyword `curl`

Comment: this comment is very important `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` :) my vote 4 u

Comment: No I haven't I'm installing it now.

Comment: Cool, if you are using windows open `php.ini` and remove `;` from the following line `;extension=php_curl.dll`

Answer (score 0):

You can use CURL request here:

**Example:**

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com'; // your url
$ch = curl_init(); // initiate
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); // curl url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result = curl_exec($ch); // curl output
$php_array = json_decode($result,true);
var_dump($php_array); 
?>
```

**Output:**

```
array(3) { ["timestamp"]=> string(8) "10:38:38" ["error_num"]=> int(404) ["error_msg"]=> string(20) "File Not Found Error" }
```

CURL give you more options to fetch remote content and error checking than to file_get_content.

Comment: nothing the same. Send me your file with a link and ill download it to try yours.

Comment: @Tim: i just copy paste my code here.. you need to chk either curl installed or not